# How to create .log file for each session and how to store that particular session data in .log file?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, log4j

In my Application, i have user like staff,student.., these user can access only some modules like staff can access only staff and student module,student can access only student module, But there is user called Admin he can access all the module. My requirement is when the admin changed any module in application then i have to store original data and change  data in file.log (i am using log4j,spring,hibernate) and i am sending that file from mail to particular user.

please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can do this directly with log4j, or any of the logging frameworks, but it sounds like what you need is an "audit" log.

The way we handled it was to create a custom annotation, @Audit, that we could apply to a method that needed to be audited.  In our case, we didn't write to a log file, but rather stored the audit record into a DB table.  You could easily setup your own annotation that used Log4J with a custom appender that wrote lines to a particular logfile.  Such a annotation might look like:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Audit {
  // Put any custom parameters here for your annotation
}
```

And then you need some way to "read" those annotations later.  We chose to use AOP like such:

```
@Aspect
@Component("auditAdvice")
@Lazy(true)
@Order(999)
public class AuditAdvice {
  @Before(value = "@annotation(audit), argNames="audit")
  public void doAudit(JoinPoint aPoint, Audit audit) {
    // Write out audit to logger here
  }
}
```

You could also use Reflections, as [this article explains](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/java-annotations-tutorial-with-custom-annotation.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, If you want to create different log file for admin for each session, try some thing like this.
Always get a Logger in your main code from a Logger Provider.

```
Logger auditLogger = AuditLogger.getLogger(username,sessionID);
//you can get the audit logger instance in any class using the above code.
//use this logger to write the change-log.
```

This is a skelton of Audit Logger implementation. You can enhance it to return a distinct logger for a session using more conditional checks.

```
public AuditLogger {

public static Logger getLogger(String username,String sessionID)
{
   //get a logger from Log4j using name+sessionID, this may return a new logger if none found
   Logger userLogger = Logger.getLogger(name+sessionID);

   Appender appender = userLogger.getAppender(name+sessionID);
   If(appender != null)
    {
      //not a first call
      return userLogger;
    }
   else
   {
      //first call for the name+sessionID combination
      RollingFileAppender app = new RollingFileAppender();
      app.setName(name+sessionID);
      app.setFile(LOG_FOLDER +"/"+name+sessionID+".log";
      //.......(set all other options..)
      // set an html layout for better formatting.
      // write your own enhanced html layout which writes more details in formatted way.
      userLogger.addAppender(app);
      app.activateOptions();
      return userlogger;
   }

}
```

This creates one distinct log for every sessions. You can use this logs to identify the change log in one session and mail it to the auditor.

You could better clean up the appender (i think by closing the appender) when the session gets destroyed. And you could also see the possibility of nullifying the logger once you are done with the usage.